# Include JS files in a xhtml file that was included using ui:include

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I will ilustrate my question using an example:

outerfile.xhtml:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.6.2.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="outer.js" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="inner_panel">
      <ui:include src="innerfile.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
```

innerfile.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition ... >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.6.2.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="inner.js" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:panelGroup>
          I Am Text in The Inner File!
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

My questions:

1. Is it okay to declare the `js` files in the inner file the way I did?
2. Do I need (And Should I) declare the common (`jquery-1.6.2.js`) again in the inner file?
3. What happens if I un-render and the re-render `inner_panel` using AJAX? Will the inner-included headers be reloaded?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Is it okay to declare the js files in the inner file the way I did?*

No. You should not specify the `<h:head>` in the include as well. This would only result in **invalid** HTML. As you have right now will result in:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <head>
      <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

*(rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see it yourself, [w3-validate](http://validator.w3.org) if necessary)*

Fix it accordingly in `innerfile.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition ... >
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.6.2.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="inner.js" target="head" />

    <h:panelGroup>
        I Am Text in The Inner File!
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

This will result in valid HTML. The scripts declared by `<h:outputScript target="head">` will just end up in the `<head>` automatically, if not already declared before. Like as in real HTML, there should be only **one** `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` in the entire view, including any templates and include files.

---

> *Do I need (And Should I) declare the common (jquery-1.6.2.js) again in the inner file?*

Not if the parent file has it already declared as `<h:outputScript>`. But redeclaring it in the include doesn't harm. It won't be duplicated anyway if it's already been declared before.

---

> *What happens if I un-render and the re-render `inner_panel` using Ajax? Will the inner-included headers be reloaded?*

This only works if you don't use `target="head"`. Whether they will be reloaded from the server, depends on whether it's already been requested by the browser before and already present and valid in the browser cache. But basically, the browser will be told again to load it, yes. With Firebug you can easily determine it.

Comment: Tnx. Small follow up - according to your answer, if I load the page when te inner page is not rendered and then render the inner page, the inner js files will be missing. Right?

Comment: I didn't said that. They will be included. The browser will be told to load them. But whether it's been obtained from the browser cache or straight from the server depends on the headers on the JS response and if it is already in browser cache or not. If it's cacheable and present in browser cache, then it won't be reloaded (because the browser already has it). Otherwise it will indeed be reloaded from server.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to write it is use target="head" inside your h:outputScript declaration on innerfile.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition ... >
    <h:outputScript library="js" target="head" name="jquery-1.6.2.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" target="head" name="inner.js" />
    <h:panelGroup>
       I Am Text in The Inner File!
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

In that way all your resource declarations will be put inside the outer . Multiple declarations of the same resource with the same library/resource name will not render the same  declaration multiple times, because the renderer for h:outputScript has some code that detect that and ignore the duplicate entries. Note things are different if you render a h:outputScript that does not reference a javascript file.